# Get Matching Xpath Count doesn't return the number of matching elements

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm working with RobotFramework and trying to get the number of elements matching 'xpath'.

```
${count}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    //*[@id="alertForm:alertDetailTabSet:0:neTable:tbody"]/tr
```

The 'xpath' must be correct. When I search by xpath on the website, it finds me 18 elements what's ok. When I start the test and then look at log output ${count} equals zero. It should be also eighteen.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I should add that I want to get the number of table rows.

Comment: Problem solved... I was on wrong website when I wanted to get that value.. If anyone can remove this question, delete it :)

Comment: thank you for updating pingwin850, hopefully we will get it removed, well done for figuring out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with `Get Count`?

```
${count}    Get Count    ${YourXpath}
log ${count}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out using the keyword Get Element Count

${count}  Get Element Count  ${YourXpath}

log ${count}